# Optimizing a webcrawl

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

The following crawl, though very short, is painfully slow. I mean, "Pop in a full-length feature film," slow.

```
def bestActressDOB():
    # create empty bday list
    bdays = []    
    # for every base url
    for actress in getBestActresses("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy_Award_for_Best_Actress"):
        # use actress list to create unique actress url
        URL = "http://en.wikipedia.org"+actress
        # connect to html
        html = urlopen(URL)
        # create soup object
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
        # get text from <span class='bday">
        try:
            bday = bsObj.find("span", {"class":"bday"}).get_text()
        except AttributeError:
            print(URL)
        bdays.append(bday)
        print(bday)
    return bdays
```

It grabs the name of every actress nominated for an Academy Award from a table on one Wikipedia page, then converts that to a list, uses those names to create URLs to visit each actresses' wiki, where it grabs her date of birth. The data will be used to calculate the age at which each actress was nominated for, or won, the Academy Award for Best Actress. Beyond Big O, is there a way to speed this up in real time.  I have little experience with this sort of thing, so I am unsure of how normal this is. Thoughts?

Edit: Requested sub-routine

```
def getBestActresses(URL):
    bestActressNomineeLinks = []
    html = urlopen(URL)
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
        table = soup.find("table", {"class":"wikitable sortable"})
    except AttributeError:
        print("Error creating/navigating soup object")
    table_row = table.find_all("tr")
    for row in table_row:
        first_data_cell = row.find_all("td")[0:1]
        for datum in first_data_cell:
            actress_name = datum.find("a")
            links = actress_name.attrs['href']
            bestActressNomineeLinks.append(links)
    #print(bestActressNomineeLinks)
    return bestActressNomineeLinks
```

Comment: If speed is №1 priority, then I'd advice to rewrite (or integrate) your parser to [`Scrapy`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/) framework.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This code is being run in Spyder right now and will be transferred to a Jupyter notebook, where it will live with the data analytics and stats it's being used to supplement. Scrapy requires a directory of it's own and couldn't be integrated with Pandas + stats packages in Jupyter, no?

Comment: Well, I think you mix up things - `Spyder` and `Jupyter` are IDEs. Scrapy if we call it in other words is a module with its own stuff, just like, for example, `BeautifulSoup` or any other module for parsing. I used `pandas` with `Scrapy`, wrote my code in `Spyder` and launched parsers from `bash`.

Comment: Something multi-threaded/asynchronous I think is @Dmitry's point. The bottleneck here is probably network IO but without seeing `getBestActresses()` it's tough to say.

Comment: @pguardiario - not sure how to multithread anything other than a needle. I'll post up getBestActresses() for your review though. There isn't much to it. It simply reads links to the actresses names from a wiki table and does so pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend trying on a faster computer or even running on a service like google cloud platform, microsoft azure, or amazon web services. There is no code that will make it go faster.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! In theory, this makes sense, but this is for a small data analysis/stats project. My Mac will have to be where it's at.  The incremental cost of learning additional technologies for this particular project is not justified by the expected payoff.

Comment: All of those services offer free version that will run it! I have used them all of the time in the past and never payed. If I was helpful please mark my answer correct so others can see it!

Comment: I'll check into them. By "incremental cost," however, I meant "additional trouble," in this context. As mentioned above, this is all going in a Jupyter notebook that will tell an analytical/statistical story. Doing everything in one place (environment) is ideal. I will, however, checkout your suggestions. If I go that route, I will certainly credit your response.